# preservation of forcing rigidity in iterations

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing

Say that a partial order $P$ is *forcing-rigid* in a model $V$ if whenever $G \subseteq P$ is generic over $V$, then in $V[G]$, $G$ is the only filter which is $P$-generic over $V$.  This implies there are no nontrivial automorphisms of $P$.

If $P$ is forcing-rigid and $P$ forces "$\dot Q$ is forcing-rigid," then is $P * \dot Q$ forcing-rigid?

Comment: I think Jensen's partial order $P$ for adding a $\Delta^1_3$ real over $L$ might provide a consistent "no" answer to your question. $P$ is certainly forcing-rigid over $L$. I *think* (but I'm not sure) it is still forcing-rigid in $L[a]$ where $a$ is $P$-generic over $L$. If so, then $P \times P$ is an example where the first p.o. is rigid in $L$, the second is rigid in the extension, but their composition (the product) is certainly not rigid, because if $(a,b)$ is a generic pair then so is $(b,a)$. It's all in chapter 28 of Jech if you want to take a look.

Comment: No. In particular assuming $\diamondsuit$ there is a rigid Souslin tree $T$ with the property that $1 \Vdash_T T_s=\{ t \in T: t \le_{T} s \}$ is rigid and Souslin, for every $s \not\in \dot{G}$. See, for example,  http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.239.2644&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: @NotMike I'd suggest giving a fuller version of your comment as an answer, since indeed it does answer Monroe's question. This is the Souslin-off-the-generic branch property that Gunter Fuchs and I had investigated in that paper, which is a strong form of rigidity.

Comment: I think that "forcing rigid" is equivalent to "the Boolean completion of $P$ is rigid".

Comment: But going a step further than you, I think that if you are careful enough, you can define a limit-ordinal-length iteration which is going to be rigid.

Comment: @AsafKaragila That is not true, and that kind of question is basically what my paper with Gunter is about (the one to which Not Mike linked). Having unique generics for a Suslin tree is the UBP property, which is strictly stronger than being rigid.

Comment: @Joel: Can you give a simple example of a forcing that has a unique generic property, but its completion is not rigid?

Comment: No, that's backwards, because UBP implies rigid. What you want is a simple example of a rigid tree that is not UBP. See figure 2 in the paper. You've got a rigid tree $T$, and $C(T)$ consists of many copies of it in a way that is rigid, yet forcing with $C(T)$ is equivalent to forcing with $T$. So $C(T)$ is rigid, but does not have UBP.

Comment: But hang on. In the paper, we argued that the tree $C(T)$ is rigid and lacked UBP, but you are talking about the Boolean completion of the tree $C(T)$. For rigidity there, one should consider it on a club of levels. Does it still work in that context?

Comment: It seems to me that the Boolean completion of the tree $C(T)$ in figure 2 is the Boolean completion of the lottery sum of $\omega$ many copies of the tree. In this case, it is not rigid, and this is not a counterexample to your claim.  Hmmnn...

Comment: But it seems to me that if we move to the more complicated example of lemma 3.6, we will get a counterexample. If $T$ is UBP, then $C'(T)$ of lemma 3.6 is a non-UBP tree that is absolutely totally rigid, and I believe that the argument of the proof shows that the Boolean completion of $C'(T)$ will be rigid, since it suffices to consider this tree on a club of levels.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins. In the paper you mention the possibility of a Suslin tree that specializes a part of itself when adding a generic branch. Do you have a reference for this kind of construction?

Comment: I think Gunter Fuchs wrote this up. He gave a talk many years ago on the construction at our seminar in New York. I'm not sure of the reference at the moment.

Comment: @Joel: It is very easy to show that the Cohen forcing can be represented as a rigid tree forcing (start with $\omega^{<\omega}$ and prune it so each node has a unique—and finite—number of successors). So certainly when you want to talk about uniqueness of generics you need to go to the Boolean completion.

Comment: Well, it is perfectly sensible to talk about unique generics without going to the Boolean algebra, especially for Souslin trees, and this sufficed for our main application to the automorphism tower problem, and that was the origin of the problem. There is a huge literature on the rigidity of Souslin trees, considered as trees. Meanwhile, in our paper we also made that same point you mentioned, if one allows non-uniform tree (different degrees), as it is trivial to make rigid trees that way. But I agree that considering the rigidity of the Boolean algebra is very natural.

Comment: Meanwhile, I also no longer believe that the example of lemma 3.6 provides a counterexample to your claim, and so I don't have a counterexample at the moment. You claim that unique generics is equivalent to the rigidity of the Boolean algebra?

Comment: @Joel: That's true, it's perfectly sensible. But it's also reasonable to talk about Boolean completion. In any case, let's call it a conjecture rather than a claim. :)

Comment: Unique generics for a complete Boolean algebra is equivalent to saying that no two distinct lower cones are isomorphic. So your conjecture is equivalent to saying: if $\mathbb{B}$ is rigid, then it is totally rigid.

Comment: I think we can prove the following: If $B$ is a complete boolean algebra, then $B$ fails to be totally rigid iff some condition forces that there are distinct $B$-generics $G,H$ such that $V[G] = V[H]$.

Comment: Yes, that is an equivalence. I made a post about this once: http://jdh.hamkins.org/common-forcing-extension-via-different-forcing-notions.

Comment: I now think I can prove Asaf's conjecture. If $\mathbb{B}$ does not have unique generics, then there are incompatible $b,c$ such that $\mathbb{B}\upharpoonright b$ and $\mathbb{B}\upharpoonright c$ are isomorphic. But $\mathbb{B}$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of these two pieces with $\mathbb{B}\upharpoonright \neg(b\vee c)$. And now we've got an automorphism swapping the first two pieces. So $\mathbb{B}$ is not rigid. Is it right?

Comment: I think that’s correct. But do you also have to assume the two generics generate the same extension?

Comment: Ah, yes, that is an issue. My argument assumes that. Hmmnn...

Comment: OK, let's make a counterexample. Suppose I have highly rigid Souslin tree $T$. Build a descending sequence of subtrees $T\supset T_1\supset T_2\supset\cdots$. Let $\mathbb{B}$ be the Boolean completion of the lottery sum of the $T_n$. This does not have unique generics, since any generic through a later tree will give me another generic through the earlier trees. But since we thinned out the trees sufficiently (is it possible?) there will be no cones on the different trees that are forcing equivalent. We'll only have compete embeddings of the later trees into the earlier, not isomorphisms.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins since the Boolean Algebra is complete, the hypothesis of Sikorski's extension theorem hold.

Comment: @NotMike Are you saying that Sikorski's extension fixes my earlier proof idea?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins it almost does. It provides a non-trivial endomorphism of $B$ into itself. Meaning that being forcing rigid is equivalent to the lack of non-identity endomorphisms.

Comment: That makes sense!  And the lack of unique generics giving rise to the whole extension is equivalent to the rigidity of the Boolean algebra. These both make sense. But are they different?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I'm tried so I'm mixing up words, when I said endomorphism above I meant  embedding (one-to-one)

Comment: I've become confused about the whole thing.

Comment: Well, so far, if you can find a pair of incompatible conditions with isomorphic cones, then you can produce a non-trivial embedding of B into itself via Sikorski's extension theorem; the question seems to be whether or not that's enough to build an automorphism. Beyond that... I've no idea

Comment: I think you can just swap elements below the isomorphic cones and fix the complement of their join. It’s easy to check that this preserves the operations.

Comment: I'm glad to have kickstarted this whole thing. Let me know when you figure out the answer. I'm going to re-watch Fargo again. :)

Comment: Doh! That's right nothing splits or is independent over the sub-algebra, since we you start with the total downward closure. So yeah, cool, totally rigid iff rigid (for complete booleans.)

Comment: I think totally rigid is equivalent to rigid for all boolean algebras.  The construction of the automorphism using an isomorphism between disjoint cones doesn't use completeness.  However, we need the completeness assumption for deducing total rigidity from unique generics.

Comment: you're right about completeness being unnecessary, not sure why I said, it's only the algebraic structure being used to define the automorphism. Actually, a density argument should suffice for deriving totally rigid from unique generics, since for every $b \not\in G$ (where $G$ is the generic), and every ultrafilter $\dot{\mathsf{F}} \in [b] \cap V[G]$ there is a dense set $D \in V$, such that $\dot{\mathsf{F}} \cap D = \emptyset$. This is only possible if,...

Comment: For every $a \in G$, and any potential order embedding $\varphi:B_a \rightarrow B_b$, the set $B_b \backslash \varphi''B_a$ is pre-dense below $b$. Since this is forced by $1_B$ to happen, we have that for every $b \in B$, with $a\perp b$, there is some $c \le a$ such that $B_c$ is not isomorphic to $B_b$.

Comment: (the condition is actually different than not-isomorphic, you only need that $B_c$ does not densely order-embed into $B_b$.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, rigidity is not preserved in iterations. In particular,

**Proposition:** If $T$ is a rigid Souslin-tree with the property that 
$$1 \Vdash_T T_{s}  =\{ t \in T : t\le_T s \}\text{ is rigid and Souslin for every }s \not\in \dot{G}$$

(rigid and Souslin off-the-generic-branch in the terminology of [FuchsHam2008](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.239.2644&rep=rep1&type=pdf).) Then,

- $1\Vdash_T $" $\check{T}$ is rigid and totally-proper."

**Proof:** Assume $T$ satisfies the required property.

To see that $T$ remains proper, fix some countable elementary sub-model $M\prec H(\lambda)$ with $T \in M$ and let $t\in T\cap M$ and $\dot{s} \in M^{T}$ be such that $t \Vdash \dot{s} \in \check{T}$.  Noting that $T$ is c.c.c., we can find some $\dot{s}_0 \in M^T$ such that $t \Vdash_T \dot{s}_0 \le_T \dot{s}$ and $\dot{s}_0 \not\in \dot{G}$. Now let $\dot{D} \in M^{T}$ be a $T$-name for a dense-open subset of $T$ and $(u,\dot{v})\le (t,\dot{s}_0)$ be any extension with $Lev_{T}(u) \ge \delta = M\cap \omega_1$  and $u \Vdash Lev_{T}(\dot{v}) \ge \check{\delta}$.

Then, we must have $ u \Vdash (\exists r \in \dot{D} \cap \check{M})(\dot{v} \le r)$ (since otherwise, a standard reflection argument yields $u \Vdash (\exists a \in T \cap M)(a \not\in \dot{G}$ and $T_a$ is not Souslin$)$). It follows that $u \Vdash_T \dot{v}$ is totally $(M[\dot{G}], \check{T})$-generic; and so $1 \Vdash_{T} \check{T}$ is totally-proper.

To see that $T$ remains rigid, note that if $t \Vdash_{T} \check{T}$ is not rigid, then for some $s \in T$ with $s \perp t$, we must have $t \Vdash_{T} \check{T}_s$ is not rigid, or $\check{T}_s$ is not c.c.c. $\square$.

**Remark:**  To see that this provides a counter-example, note that the two-step iteration of $T$ with itself is isomorphic to the square $T^2$ which admits the non-trivial automorphism $(s,t)\rightarrow (t,s)$. (being totally-proper in the extension didn't really matter, I just thought it was worth pointing out.)

Comment: For totally proper, perhaps it is easier to observe that $T$ remains locally c.c.c. after forcing with $T$, because once you have a condition off the generic branch, then it is Suslin below that condition. (Locally c.c.c. = for every condition, there is a stronger condition below which the forcing is c.c.c.)

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins you're right. Thanks for pointing that out. I had been screwing around with the idea of weakening the souslin off-the-generic hypothesis, and lost perspective.